# Regular expression for uppercase, lowercase and number

Tags: python, regex, numbers, uppercase, lowercase

My task is to validate a string that must contain at least one lowercase and uppercase character and at least one number. I don't have to check the length of this string.

I'm trying to do something like this:

```
from re import match


regexp = "^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])"
string_to_validate = input("Write string with uppercase/lowercase characters and numbers.")
if not match(regexp, string_to_validate):
    raive ValueError("You should use uppercase and lowercase characters with numbers in your string")
```

But it seems to me that there's an expression for this purpose that is much better than that one. Honestly, I don't even know what the symbol '^' at the beginning of the expression is used for.

Comment: That's the standard way to write this regexp. `^` matches the beginning of the string -- that should be explained in any regexp tutorial.

Comment: You don't need the `^` for this.

Comment: There are many different regexes you could write to solve this problem - they are only 'better' if they meet some requirement you have that this one doesn't. What exactly is your question, other than "is there a better regex?" - because the answer is "probably". To do what you're asking, a regex isn't even necessarily the best solution - do you need to use a regex? Why? If this is homework, isn't the aim that you learn about regexes yourself?

Comment: If you're unsure, write three simple regexes instead trying to come with one complicated regex.

Comment: If you've found this in other solutions, they also have an additional restriction of the password length. In that case you will need to anchor with `^` and `$` to count the characters in the password.

Comment: On a side note, it's a good practice to use raw string, i.e., `r"^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])"` instead of `"^(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9])"`, for RegEx pattern.

Answer (score 2):

It is more maintainable and more readable to break up the requirements into individual regexes, and to use [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search):

```
import re

strs = ['Bb2', 'Bb', 'b2', 'B2']
for s in strs:
    if not (re.search(r'[A-Z]', s)
            and re.search(r'[a-z]', s)
            and re.search(r'\d', s)):
        print(f'Input "{s}" must contain at least 1 uppercase letter, 1 lowercase letter and 1 digit.')
    else:
        print(f'Input "{s}" is OK')
# Input "Bb2" is OK
# Input "Bb" must contain at least 1 uppercase letter, 1 lowercase letter and 1 digit.
# Input "b2" must contain at least 1 uppercase letter, 1 lowercase letter and 1 digit.
# Input "B2" must contain at least 1 uppercase letter, 1 lowercase letter and 1 digit.
```